# Opacity and jQuery fadeIn/fadeOut in firefox extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox-addon, opacity

I'm having a hard time getting jquery fades and the opacity css element to respond to me in a firefox extension that I am writing. I am using FireFox 3.6. I'm pretty sure that these two problems are related.

This code is not fading, it is simply popping on and off the screen after a four second wait:

```
css_notify_div = {
    position: 'fixed',
    top: '2%',
    right: '2%',
    font: 'bold',
    'font-size': '1.5em',
    'font-family': 'sans-serif',
    'text-align': 'center',
    'background-color': 'ffff88',
    'border': '2px solid #eeee00',
    'padding': '5px',
    margin: 'auto',
    display: 'none'
};


doc = window.content.document;
$('#br_notify_div', doc).css(css_notify_div);

$('#br_notify_div', doc).fadeIn("slow", function () {
    $('#br_notify_div', doc).fadeOut(4000);
});
```

fadeTo() also fails every time I run it, and if I use css({opacity:'.2'}) then nothing happens either.

Edit: This appears to be specific to a firefox extension environment. The other animations work fine, show('slow') for instance looks just fine. This appears to be related to using the opacity property itself, it doesn't seem to be just a jQuery issue.

Answer (score 1):

I tried it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fqTF4/) and it seemed to work fine..?

(FF 3.6.6 on linux)

Comment: Looks like it has something to do with having to grab the document. Because I'm in a firefox extension I have to refer to window.content.document.

Comment: It works ok using window.document. I get a 'permissions error' trying to use 'window.content.document' that looks like some attempt at cross-site protection. Is your script coming from the same domain as the html?

Comment: Window.content is only used when you declare your javascript from inside a XUL document in a firefox extension. Window.document in that context returns elements representing menu items, sidebars, and toolbars. So in that case we goto window.content.document to get the web page object.